# Running batch files in python

Tags: python, batch-processing

I have a set of codes that I want to run in sequence through a .py file instead of a .bat file, how can I do so? I have the following code for doing so:

```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   import sys
   import os
   bashCommand = "./available_itemsawk.sh"
   os.system(bashCommand)
   python_command="python run_process.py"
   os.system(python_command)
```

I have two questions:
1) I have the shell script(available_itemsawk.sh) as follows:

```
  #!/bin/bash
  join -1 4 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2 <(sort -k4 abc.txt) <(sort -k1 cdf.txt) > join.txt
  awk '{print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4"\t"$5"\t"$6}' join.txt > temp
  mv temp join.txt
```

However when I call and run it through the python script ,I am getting following errors:

```
  sort: write failed: standard output: Broken pipe
  sort: write error
```

2) How to run the scripts in series through os.system process?

```
      abc.txt
      chr7  99999667    100000138   ENSG00000078487:I17.1       -
      chr7  100000139   100000199   ENSG00000078487:E17.1   ENSE00001180416 -
      chr9  100000046   100000367   ENSG00000203279:E2.1    ENSE00001678182 -
      chr3  99998605    100000561   ENSG00000036054:I5.1        +
      chr3  100000562   100000586   ENSG00000036054:E6.1    ENSE00001916783 +
      chr3  100000586   100000691   ENSG00000036054:E6.2    ENSE00003639820|ENSE00001916783 +
      chr9  99983518    100000704   ENSG00000159712:I1.1        -
      chr9  100000368   100000704   ENSG00000203279:I1.1        -
      chr9  100000731   100000765   ENSG00000254876:E1.1    ENSE00002183448 +
      chr9  100000765   100000779   ENSG00000197816:E1.1    ENSE00003621967 +


      cdf.txt
      ENSG00000078487:I17.1
      ENSG00000254876:E1.1
      ENSG00000036054:E6.1  
      ENSG00000036054:I5.1  
      ENSG00000197816:E1.1
```

Comment: Looks like an error in the shell script itself, independent of python. Can you confirm that when you execute the shell script directly it works?

Comment: @quantum_random: It is running just fine independently, and also I am using mac terminal as the platform to run the codes.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the contents in abc.txt and cdf.txt? I can try to repro this on my end. I am using Ubuntu, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I put it up in the question.

Comment: I tried this on my computer and everything runs just fine. Of course I did not run the python_command in your code above. One explanation is that the 'Broken pipe' error is from run_process.py instead of the shell script. Try commenting out the last two lines of your code and see if the error still happens. Otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: @quantum_random: I did try doing that and the error is in running the shell script from the python code.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment (don't have 50pts yet), here's my best guess.

This seems like a permissions issue.  Either individual permissions on each script (batch and python), or what you're defining in the header of your scripts.

Your python script contains `#!/usr/bin/python` while your batch file has `#!/bin/bash`

This might not be the core of your issue.  But it got me thinking that perhaps one of your .py scripts is owned by or being executed by a user with lower permissions than required by your batch script, or perhaps one of your .txt files.

I'd make sure all your script and input/output files don't require elevated permissions.  Are you running these as a user or root?  Are these readable, writable, executable by user or just root?

[Arch Linux file permissions wiki entry.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/File_permissions_and_attributes)